# How to add photos from a url to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

My code retrieves photos from urls and using file_put_contents add them to the current directory, but I need it to add them to /wordpress/wp-content/uploads where wordpress save the manually uploaded files.

```
$Address = "www.xxx.com/" . $file;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$url = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$location = "/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/a.jpg"; 
file_put_contents($location, file_get_contents($url));
if(! function_exists('wp_upload_dir'))
                {
                    define('WP_USE_THEMES',false);
                    require 'wordpress/wp-load.php';
                }
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
    echo $upload_dir['path'];
    echo $upload_dir['url'];
    echo $upload_dir['subdir'];
```

I even copied the following part in my index file but it did not solve the problem

```
  if(! function_exists('wp_upload_dir'))
                    {
                        define('WP_USE_THEMES',false);
                        require 'wordpress/wp-load.php';
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_path = $uploads['baseurl']; // get uploads dir

rename("a.jpg", trailingslashit($upload_path) . "a.jpg"); // move
```

ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir
ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

**UPDATE**

I guess that you are working outside of WP. Try this to get `wp_upload_dir()` and all WP functionality before your code:

```
if ( ! function_exists('wp_upload_dir'))
{
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require PATH_WP_DIR . '/wp-load.php';
    // ex: require '/wordpress/wp-load.php';
}
```

Comment: @saeed-pirdost OK, give it look to my update. This code will work. Any other issue open a new question.... Good luck.

Comment: put the `require...` at the most earlier stage as possible.

Comment: If I open a new question that would be a duplicate of this one so I updated the question

Comment: @saeed-pirdost I meant that **your original** question (I recommend you to use **UPDATE** to add more info each time) already has a good solution. Now your problem is how to get `wp_upload_dir` works. That **is another question**. Good luck...